# Postgresql is not getting data from form

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

***I'm learning django now, and i'm facing a problem, I create a form to submite data in my database, but the problem is when i click on submit button, postgres isn't receiving data, I cant understand the problem.***

[This is my contact form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRbf1.png)
[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8hp1.png)

## This is my html code

```
 <form action="." method='post' class="p-5 bg-white">          
 <h2 class="h4 text-black mb-5">Contact Form</h2> 
 {% csrf_token %}
 <div class="row form-group">
 <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 mb-md-0">
 <label class="text-black" for="fname">First Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="fname" class="form-control rounded-0">
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <label class="text-black" for="lname">Last Name</label>
 <input type="text" id="lname" class="form-control rounded-0">
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row form-group">

 <div class="col-md-12">
 <label class="text-black" for="email">Email</label> 
 <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control rounded-0">
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row form-group">

 <div class="col-md-12">
 <label class="text-black" for="subject">Subject</label> 
 <input type="subject" id="subject" class="form-control rounded-0">
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <label class="text-black" for="message">Message</label> 
 <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="7" class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Leave your message here..."></textarea>
 </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row form-group">
 <div class="col-md-12">
 <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary mr-2 mb-2">
 </div>
 </div>
 </form>
```

## This is my models.py

```
 from django.db import models

 class Form(models.Model):

 fname=models.CharField(max_length=300)
 lname=models.CharField(max_length=300)
 email=models.EmailField()
 subject=models.CharField(max_length=300)
 message=models.TextField()
```

## This is my views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from .models import Form

 def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.POST.get('fname')
        request.POST.get('lname')
        request.POST.get('email')
        request.POST.get('subject')
        request.POST.get('message')
        post=Form()

        post.fname= request.POST.get('fname')
        post.lname= request.POST.get('lname')
        post.email= request.POST.get('email')
        post.subject= request.POST.get('subject')
        post.message= request.POST.get('message')
        post.save() 
    else:
        return render(request,'test.html')
```

Comment: You are missing some kind of dependency here. Try checking your settings.py file and see if there is something that you have not configured correctly

Comment: I'm not sure `action="."` is right... If you have no `action` then it will use the current url which is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

1st. In the form action="." is not necessary as if action is empty it will be sent to the current view itself.

2nd. I suggest using Model Forms which are a lot easier.

Let's say the model name is M1.

*models.py*

```
from django.db import models

class M1(models.Model):

    fname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField()
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    message = models.TextField()
```

*forms.py*

```
from django import forms

M1Form(forms.modelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = M1
```

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import M1
from .forms import M1Form

def test(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = M1Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            return render(request, "test.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "test.html")
```

3rd. If you look at the Templates:

```
<input type="email" id="email" class="form-control rounded-0">
```

it does not have an attribute "**name**" in it. If you want email in request.POST It should be written like

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control rounded-0">
```

Please keep in mind that the **name** should be the same as the model name (Since we are not overwitting the Form).

For more Documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/